# Half Space: Total Derivative vs. Partial Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

**Setting**

Given a function $f:\mathbb{H}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

Denote the right-pointing unit vector by: $n\perp\partial\mathbb{H}^m$

**Boundary Point: Total Derivative**

First, suppose its one-sided total derivative exists at a boundary point:
$$a\in\partial\mathbb{H}^m:\quad\frac{1}{\|v\|}\left\|f(a+v)-f(a)-Df(a)v\right\|\stackrel{v\to 0}{\to}0\quad(v\in\mathbb{H}^m)$$
Then, it admits an extension whose ordinary total derivative exists there:
$$a\in\partial\mathbb{H}^m:\quad\frac{1}{\|v\|}\left\|f_E(a+v)-f_E(a)-Df(a)v\right\|\stackrel{v\to 0}{\to}0$$
The extension being given by reflection *around the point*:
$$a\in\partial\mathbb{H}^m:\quad f_E(a-v):=-f(a+v)\quad(v\notin\mathbb{H}^m)$$

**Boundary Line: Partial Derivative**

Next, suppose its one-sided partial derivative exists along the boundary line:
$$x\in\partial\mathbb{H}^m:\quad\frac{1}{|h|}\left\|f(x+v)-f(x)-h\partial_nf(x)\right\|\stackrel{h\to 0}{\to}0\quad(h\geq0)$$
Then, it admits an extension whose ordinary partialal derivative exists there:
$$x\in\partial\mathbb{H}^m:\quad\frac{1}{|h|}\left\|f(x+v)-f(x)-h\partial_nf(x)\right\|\stackrel{h\to 0}{\to}0$$
The extension being given by reflection *along the line*:
$$x\in\partial\mathbb{H}^m:\quad f_E(x-hn):=2f(a)-f(x+hn)\quad(h<0)$$

**Boundary Line: Total Derivative**

> Finally, suppose its one-sided total derivative exists along the boundary line:
>   $$x\in\partial\mathbb{H}^m:\quad\frac{1}{\|v\|}\left\|f(a+v)-f(a)-Df(a)v\right\|\stackrel{v\to 0}{\to}0\quad(v\in\mathbb{H}^m)$$
>   Does it also admit an extension who's ordinary total derivative exists there?
>   $$x\in\partial\mathbb{H}^m:\quad\frac{1}{\|v\|}\left\|f(a+v)-f(a)-Df(a)v\right\|\stackrel{v\to 0}{\to}0$$
>   The problem is that the reflection *around a point* and *along a line* clash.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in \partial \mathbb{H}^m$ and $ v$ is orthogonal to $\partial \mathbb{H}^m$, pointing into $ \mathbb{H}^m $, have you considered the definition $$ f_E(a-tv) :=2 f(a)-f(a+tv)$$
Note that then $f_E(a) = f(a)$, so $f_E(a-tv) - f_E(a) + tLv = f(a) -f(a+tv) +tLv $.

Just a guess, I did not check the details.

Comment: This would be the obvious guess for at least straight lines so guaranteeing directional derivative but still leaking for spirals so guaranteeing total derivative...

Comment: This actually fails see the answer above